# Breadcrumbs display vertical instead of Horizontal at Prestashop default theme (1.6.1.10)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Im attaching the image of how its look like, but also the link itself:
http://sunray.co.il/index.php (Due to right now)

```css
.breadcrumb {

  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  border-radius: 0px; }
  .breadcrumb > li {
    display: inline-block; }
    .breadcrumb > li + li:before {
      content: "/\00a0";
      padding: 0 5px;
      color: #333; }
  .breadcrumb > .active {
    color: #333; }
```

[image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocu8y.jpg)

Thanks everbody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to css:

```
span.navigation_page li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

or change the

```
 .breadcrumb > li {
    display: inline-block; }
```

to

```
 .breadcrumb li {
    display: inline-block; }
```

Because the li is not immediately after the class breadcrumb.

Comment: @AvivS If it worked then the least you can do is accept his answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

add this to your breadcrumb css:

```
.breadcrumb a {display: inline-block;}
```